# Java Hashmap Tail Traversing

Tags: java, linked-list, hashmap

What does tail traversing mean in Java Hashmap? Java reverses the (linked list) bucket having more than one element. The reversal is done to avoid Tail Traversing and adding an element to the head. I cannot understand this concept.

Comment: What implementation of `Hashmap` are you talking about?

Comment: All the uses of the term "tail traversing" or "tail traversal" I can find seem to trace back to a few dubious blog posts. No official source uses the term. Nothing in the source or documentation says anything about it. I recommend not using the term.

Comment: TedHopp I am talking about the race condition that may occur when a hash map runs out of space, and tries to double its size.

Comment: @user2357112 then what is the mechanism behind this? Is there any other working?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> I came to this blog searching for an answer about what tail traversal
>   is and now i had an Epiphany

Dhananjayan, 
what this basically means is that tail traversing is a concept in linked list. i will try to explain this with an example. 
lets say you want to add the following elements to a singly linked list

**23, 65, 44, 12, 90**

Ok fine now. you have added 5 elements. so after some time , you need to add a new element **10**. so  if our algorithm adds elements to end of linked list, it has to traverse through theese five elements to find the tail which can be quite expensive in case of lengthy linked lists. so one efficient way is to add new elements to head instead of tail and change the head pointer to point to new head.so in this case when you add a new element 10, linked list would look like following

**10, 23, 65, 44, 12, 90**

As you can see, this is a very efficient approach.

I will answer your second question now(What do they mean by reversing?)
So in hashmap when they resize/rehash, they pull up elements from linked list starting from head and make a new linked list and add subsequent elements in order so on each iteration the result will be

- 10
- 23 10
- 65 23 10
- 44 65 23 10
- 12 44 65 23 10
- **90 12 44 65 23 10**

so this is the result of adding new elements to head
In short this is a LIFO(Last in First out) structure.

Philip

Comment: Philip can you explain why putting new element at head is a better optimization because I may need to access the value which is at the tail someday i.e. in 10 - 23 - 65 - 44 - 12 - 90 it is not necessary that I will always need to say get() the node with value 10. I will need 90 someday and this will mean I have to go till the tail anyway.  
Also, why is the reversing done? Does that add any efficiency? I can always copy from one linked list to another with same efficiency in the same order (and not reversed).

Comment: Mustafa, They are putting new elements in head because if we add element in the tail(like a queue) , we have to traverse the entire linklist to find the tail which is a waste of time when we can just put it in head and Go. In Algorothimic lingo the efficiency is O(n) for adding element to end and O(1) for adding to head. Yes, you may need to access the 90 someday and if you think adding to head would've saved you, what if we needed 10 or 12? So my point is , for searching an element in a linear list, you have to go through it all. its O(n).

Comment: Mustaffa, Continued... So they can't save anything on search. so they thought 'what the hell, we may as well increase the efficiency of insertion'. also, you may know the temporal locality which says that the last used variables have a high chance of being used again . so there's a good chance that 10 will be used in near future(just a guess ok? no official docs says this). Copying a linklist won't work because. when we resize, HASH value has to be recomputed and most probably, these elements may scatter to different buckets.  Huge Explanation for a short question I KNOW!...

Comment: Thanks Philip - Your explanation and http://mailinator.blogspot.hu/2009/06/beautiful-race-condition.html made it very very clear.

Comment: @PhilipGeorge why we need to traverse linked list while inserting node?

Comment: @PhilipGeorge singly linked list takes O(1) time complexity while adding elements to it in average and worst case

Answer (score 2):

To answer Sufian's question. Yes you are correct for traversal we need to traverse the whole linked list. But this thread is solely related to hash collision resolution. One of the the method to solve has collision is to restructure the whole linked list that is stored in a bucket. So hashmap creates a new linkedlist from the old one. and this TRAIL TRAVERSING happens only during that time of recreation.

Answer (score 2):

Philiph answers above explains what is tail traversing and why does reversing occur. In java HashMap when a element is inserted anyhow it does tail traversing in order to check whether there are duplicates in the linked list by making equals() operation on every single element. I see many people advocate that adding element in head has an advantage in HashMap, but if you are already doing tail traversing then why not add it to tail if you find no match and hit a null link to the next link from the tail. According to me there is no advantage of adding the element in the head because it does tail traversing in order to check for the existence of the key already. So i see the only sole reason to add in head is temporal locality as Philiph mentions. Is that influences so much that it be added into the head? because you access the last inserted element is uncertain.

Answer (score 1):

In `HashMap` we always need to traverse through linked list even if there is an existing linked list at particular index for checking against key.

```
for (Entry<K,V> e = table[i]; e != null; e = e.next) {
    ......................
}
```

so even if add new entry at top , how will it avoid tail traversing , since we anyway need to traverse for key checking?
where at last after checking if we dont find same key, we can add the new entry at last.